# Need help understanding jQuery syntax order of operation

Tags: jquery, css

So far I've been trying to descramble other people's code and methods for deploying effective and elegant jQuery, but I'm constantly given options that later confuse me for what I should be paying attention to. This usually devolves into a few calls that I'm sure can be simplified.

What I'm trying to do is

1-check if an `id` has a particular declaration name (the id name),

2-remove the `controlbar` class if it does not end with M4V or

3-if `#postvideo` is empty, or if it just plain'ol does not exist in the parent div of `articlePost` hide `.controlbar`

4-But if it does end in M4V, detach it and append it and it's element attributes to the element `#fold-above`... Simple right? I know, probably not.

Sample code I'm trying to work with:

```
$('#postvideo').not('[src$=".m4v"]').empty().each(function() { 
    $(".controlbar").remove();  //elements whose src doesn't end with `.m4v`
});

$('.articlePost').empty('$("#postvideo").function() {
    $(".controlbar").remove();
});

$("#postvideo").detach().appendTo("#fold-above");
```

Same `id`, multiple calls. Can anyone help explain how and why it would be better to put all of this into concise code?

Comment: Can you explain the 3rd point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".controlbar").remove();` would remove all items with class controlbar - so the same each time. No need to use each for that and if you want to just remove the class try this instead

```
$('#postvideo .controlbar').not('[src$=".m4v"]').each(function() {
  $(this).empty().removeClass("controlbar");
});
```

or even shorter as Arun showed...

Comment: `.controlbar` exists within the parent `div` of `#postvideo`. it was my impression that the DOM call for `remove`ing `.controlbar` would trail up from the root call of `body` and take it out before reaching up to the `#postvideo` call... Which is where my confusion might be starting.

Answer (score 1):

Your first part can be written as

```
$('#postvideo').not('[src$=".m4v"]').empty().removeClass('controlbar');
```